# Auto sign out from pinax account

Tags: django, pinax

Is there a way to configure the pinax project to automatically sign out a user after a period of inactivity? Are you aware of any other alternative route, like a django app or so?

Comment: checkout this snippet ..https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/449/